# Application with interchangeable persistance layer

Tags: java, design-patterns, persistence, data-access-layer, domain-object

In 95% of examples I see, people are adding `@Entity` or `@Document` annotations to their domain objects.

I would like to create an app in which I can easily change persistence layer.
It should be possible to switch in settings from `SQL DB` to e.x. `MongoDB` etc.

I want to keep my domain objects completely independent from persistence layer.

I have thought about something like this:
[image]

Where `Item` is a domain object.

```
public interface ItemsRepository {

    List<Item> getItems();
}
```

Each `ItemsRepository` implementation has it's own dedicated persistence layer object. For SQL it will be let's say `ItemEntity` class, for Mongo `ItemDocument` class. And each persistence object has conversion from and to domain object.

Is approach like this acceptable? If not, what are the best industry patterns to solve that problem?

Comment: Spring Data does this for you.

Comment: "*Is approach like this acceptable?*" - Yes. This is the [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and belongs to the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Comment: Correction: It is the [Separation of Concerns principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), not the Interface segregation principle. In essence, the persistence is a separate concern and thus should be separated out (entirely, including data classes for the specific persistence layer).

Comment: @BoristheSpider But in order to use `Spring Data JPA` or `Spring Data MongoDb` you still need to have these dedicated Entities/Documents.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider this a good application of the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). I'm not saying this to counter the other comments to the question, but rather to highlight that this sort of design seems defensible when looked at from more than one perspective. I [often design code bases according to a similar structure](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/03/layers-onions-ports-adapters-its-all-the-same). Yes, I'd say that it's more than acceptable.